# Escaping spaces in powershell LDAP path

Tags: powershell, ldap, space

I have the following powershell code:

```
 $strCategory = "computer"

 $objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Computers,OU=2 Streetsville,DC=ourdomain,DC=local")

 $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($objDomain)
 $objSearcher.Filter = ("(objectCategory=$strCategory)")

 $colProplist = "name"
 foreach ($i in $colPropList){[void]$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}

 $colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
```

The code worked fine when our LDAP path contained no spaces:

```
LDAP://OU=Computers,OU=DataCenter,DC=ourdomain,DC=local
```

However when we renamed our DataCenter OU to an address:

```
LDAP://OU=Computers,OU=2 Streetsville,DC=ourdomain,DC=local
```

Suddenly the code no longer works.

I figured no problem I just need to escape the space with a `\`:

```
LDAP://OU=Computers,OU=2\ Streetsville,DC=ourdomain,DC=local
```

However that doesn't work. I also tried a double slash to escape the space:

```
LDAP://OU=Computers,OU=2\\ Streetsville,DC=ourdomain,DC=local
```

I'm at a loss for what else to try. I could go back to a spaceless OU name but I'd rather not. Can someone help me figure out how to properly escape the space?

Comment: What's not working? Do you get an error? You should be able to list the objects even with a space in the path.

Comment: Yes I get the following error: Exception calling "FindAll" with "0" argument(s): "There is no such object on the server. " At C:\scripts\LogZipAndMove.ps1:15 char:35 + $colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll <<<< () + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this link, specifically the Powershell and ADSI section which has multiple examples of escaping characters:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx

The space in your LDAP shouldn't be an issue but maybe the combinations of single quotes and double quotes. We have OUs with spaces and constructing the LDAP query in double quotes works fine:

```
$searchme = [ADSI]"LDAP://OU=Computers,OU=2 Streetsville,DC=ourdomain,DC=local"
 $search = [adsisearcher]$searchme
 $colResults = $search.FindAll()
```

The error you're receiving is saying the OU being passed in doesn't exist, which indicates a potential typo in the LDAP string, might be worth double checking the spelling.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 .... DirectoryEntry('LDAP://OU=Computers,OU="2 Streetsville",DC=ourdomain,DC=local')
```

Comment: No joy - still doesn't work. PS C:\scripts> .\LogZipAndMove.ps1
Exception calling "FindAll" with "0" argument(s): "There is no such object on the server.
"
At C:\scripts\LogZipAndMove.ps1:15 char:35
+ $colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: @Brad. Have you try my edited answer? In my domain anyway I don't need to escape or quote OU with space... maybe your error lives in other place..

Comment: Actually if I get rid of the space it still doesn't work. Maybe I have to escape the number also?

Comment: Actually it works without a space and with a number - but the number is at the end. Maybe the first character being a number is the problem?